# How do I catch a timeout?

Tags: vb.net, exception, timeoutexception

I'm trying to catch a timeout for logging purposes but it doesn't seem to be working, my try catch below:

```
    Try
     'code here
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        log.Error("ApplicantCreate Timed out - " & ex.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        log.Error("ApplicantCreate - " & ex.Message)
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
```

As you can see I'm using TimeoutException but when I check the event viewer logs (where I'm logging other messages to currently) no timeout error appears. Meaning that the TimeoutException must not be hit, what do I need to do to catch the timeout?

Comment: Is the other message logged instead? Check the documentation of the thing you use in *code here* to see if that's the correct exception type thrown by whatever your using.

Comment: I'm just trying to load an xml string and parse through it in the code here section, just felt like it would take attention away from the try catch if I posted it too.

Comment: What is it you expect to throw TimeoutException ?

Comment: I'll explain the setup I have for this, I have a test app that is using the web service, while I'm debugging if I just let it sit and do nothing for about 30 seconds while it's trying to parse the xml it tells me "The operation has timed out" in my test app (which is a windows application). So it must be catching it on that side I imagine?

Comment: The 'code here' block it's very relevant here.... The operation has timed out, may be a System.Net.WebException, really

Comment: Set a breakpoint because it should be catching the TimeoutException...

Comment: In where your setting: **log.Error("ApplicantCreate Timed out - " & ex.Message)**, change that to: **log.Error("ApplicantCreate Timed out - " & ex.GetType().ToString)** and see if that helps... But you need to make sure it's actually catching the exception by setting a breakpoint.

Comment: I had set a breakpoint in there and it wasn't entering, it's not a big deal now anyways. The client gave us some more clarity on what exactly they wanted, they want it to catch sql timeout errors which it seems to be doing fine. This one's on the back burner for now, thanks again!